# What is difference in Date and DateTime DataType in c#

Tags: c#, date, datetime

Example : I get myDataTable from database through some query (Lot of different queries) and want to change the `Date` and `DateTime` fields to user desired presentation.

```
void dgv_DataSourceChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     for (int i = 0; i < dgv.Columns.Count; i++)
     {
          if (myDataTable.Columns[i].DataType == typeof(DateTime))
              dgv.Columns[i].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
          else
          {
              if (myDataTable.Columns[i].DataType == typeof(Date))
                  dgv.Columns[i].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "dd-MM-yyyy";
          }
     }
}
```

You can see there is no problem with columns having DataType=`DateTime`, but how can I handle the `Date` dataType regardless of my current database query? Date is available in database but not in c#.

**Update** : I can do this through checking the ending of date value weather it is 12:00: AM or 00:00:00. But this seems a bogus solution a real DateTime value can also have the same value. This value does not guarantee that DataType is `Date` and not DateTime

Comment: `datetime.Date == datetime` => `true` when a date.

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach( DataRow dr in datatable.Rows)
{
    DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(dr["YourDateTimeColumnName"], 
                              "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    string s = dt.ToString("dd/M/yyyy");
}
```

now your DateTime is converted to Date and you can use it in DataGridView.

Comment: Wajid Sahib! have you tried it because `myDataTable.Columns[i].ToString()` does not seem much correct (mean can it work without using any row number?)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can not distinguish. What you can do in this particular case is

```
for (int i = 0; i < dgv.Columns.Count; i++)
{
    if (source.Columns[i].DataType == typeof(DateTime))
    {
        string val = source.Rows[0][i].ToString();
        if (val.EndsWith("12:00:00 AM") ||val.EndsWith("00:00:00"))
        {
            dgv.Columns[i].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "yyyy-MM-dd"; 
            //Your date Format
        }
        else
           dgv.Columns[i].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
           //Your date and Time Format
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is only *DateTime* datatype available in C# for *datetime*, *date* datatype of SQL Sever.

See the following datatype mapping table for reference:
[SQL Server Data Type Mappings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716729.aspx)